# run a query every 5mins from a Windows Application using C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, windows

I am creating a Windows Application which will run in the background and run a query every 5 mins. If it finds a record based on the criteria the application will make a sound to notify me. How can run a query inside a Windows Application every 5 mins? and how can i specify the connection string from within a memo box in my form?

I have created the application, added the button to start the app and added the textbox for the connection string.

Comment: Show your code so that people can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create your timer

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
```

set it up

```
timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick); 
timer.Interval = (1000 * 60 * 5);           
timer.Enabled = true;       
timer.Start();
```

do stuff when it ticks

```
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //run query, play noise
}
```

Comment: Why `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`? and not `System.Timers.Timer` or `System.Threading.Timer` ?

Comment: thanks, no to work out how to connect to the DB via my application!

Comment: I like people like you because you have answered the question based your understanding which is perfect, and you have not sad its duplicate, blablabla.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways. I've worked on projects that use schedulers that are configured in the web.config. There are other projects that use the Windows Scheduler on the server to run something every so often.

This question--[How to write C# Scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764812/how-to-write-c-sharp-scheduler) has a way to do it within the C# code itself.